# Creating EDI from Guidelines

Tags: edi

I'm new to EDI, In my project I want to create EDI file from EDI design Guidelines. Can anyone help me for creating EDi from guidelines document.

Comment: this isn't really a programming question. It's more of a getting started question

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating an EDI file you must be sending an outbound message to one of your trading partners. Your EDI design Guidelines MUST match theirs e.g. Protocol / Message Version etc so ensure that you are creating the file to their published specification.

There are some tools to create EDI Messages from structured design definitions. The Foresight EDISIM product may assist you here. However I would concentrate on mapping your own business data to the EDI Design Guidelines and to maximise this investment consider as many trading partners as possible that could also benefit from this outbound message.

You want to get as many trading partners using the same translation/map with as little change as possible. It sounds like you need a EDI translator. There are several products but the BOTS program is free. http://bots.sourceforge.net/